# Выборка по нескольким полям с максимальным количеством совпадений

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с несколькими полями типа INT

Например:

| id1 | id2 | id3 | id4 | id5 | id6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 8 | 4 |
| 6 | 1 | 8 | 2 | 7 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 6 | 1 | 9 | 5 |
| 9 | 7 | 8 | 3 | 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 2 | 7 | 4 | 8 | 5 |

Как сделать поиск, что бы найти строки с максимальным количеством совпадений.
Если запрос может быть из 2, 3, ... , 6 параметров.
Т.е. нужно например найти сроки где есть 2,4,8 в любом из столбцов т.е. надо получить первую и последнюю строку.
И если нет точного совпадения то хотя бы с двумя совпадениями.

Comment: Это кто ж такую структуру придумал? нет бы нормализовать... пиши теперь критерий сортировки в форме суммы шести `!!FIND_IN_SET()`, куда теперь деваться...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, (FIND_IN_SET(id1, @criteria) > 0) + 
                        (FIND_IN_SET(id2, @criteria) > 0) + 
                        (FIND_IN_SET(id3, @criteria) > 0) + 
                        (FIND_IN_SET(id4, @criteria) > 0) + 
                        (FIND_IN_SET(id5, @criteria) > 0) + 
                        (FIND_IN_SET(id6, @criteria) > 0) matches 
               FROM test )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE matches = ( SELECT MAX(matches)
                  FROM cte );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=54f49c76560db74ceda04a5687b86cf4)